# What is the maximum frequency for a diode if a superimposed AC sine wave on DC pass through it, and the diode stays always ON due to DC?

Tags: voltage, diodes, frequency, zener, dropout

How can I determine if a forward biased diode (always ON) can be used to pass the full band of a superimposed AC sine wave on DC?

The diode is just used as a protection device against possible reverse voltages coming from the load. In normal operation in such way causes only about 0.7 V drop of the DC.

In particular I need to determine the frequency response of the  P1000S and SF5408 diode for a 20-100 kHz DC biased wave.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the diode is used as a switching device, the frequency doesn't matter, at least for the range you are working with.

If the amplitude of the AC is high enough to "turn off" the diode or reverse bias it periodically (e.g. a 10-Vpk AC with a 5 VDC offset) then the junction capacitance and the reverse recovery time come into play.

Otherwise, the frequency doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

A diode always in forward bias, has voltage drop and incremental resistance corresponding to instantaneous current.

This is true regardless of type, and applies from DC, up to frequencies where junction capacitance dominates over incremental resistance, or stray inductance (due to lead and body length) dominates over both.

Mind, for a power rectifier, inductance could dominate at mere MHz.  If your wave has harmonics, this might be relevant, but if total bandwidth is as stated, it's unlikely to matter.

Note that incremental resistance depends on current.  This a nonlinear element, which can create distortion.  If the precise voltage drop matters, you may want to consider an alternative method with better linearity.  I have no idea if distortion matters; the nature of this signal is unstated.  I can only suggest this as a hint in case it does matter.

(There is also the special case where, for frequencies faster than the reverse recovery time, the diode can remain conductive even if the instantaneous current reverses for part of the cycle.  Diodes designed for this mode of operation are called RF switching PIN diodes.  Your P1000S is most likely of this type (PIN, that is), actually.  The SF5408 is a fast type which would not be usable this way.  In any case, this recovery effect is not relevant here, as the current is not reversing, and the frequency is below the reciprocal recovery time of either type.)